# Is beer healthy if drunk in moderation?

Tags: health

Beer is obviously not healthy if it is drunk to much, however, one of my friends argue a little beer in moderation can provide certain health benefits. Like it can lower risk of stroke and heart diseases. Is this true or is it just baloney people say to get someone else to drink a little bit?
Are these claims true?

Comment: Yes but they would rather you use the alcohol on red wine and a max of 12 oz a day.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8605457?dopt=Citation) research paper published in BMJ they concluded the following:

> Results from observational studies, where alcohol consumption can be
>   linked directly to an individual's risk of coronary heart disease,
>   provide strong evidence that all alcoholic drinks are linked with
>   lower risk. Thus, a substantial portion of the benefit is from alcohol
>   rather than other components of each type of drink.

This argues that health benefits are alcohol related and not specifically beer related. This is, again, during moderate consumption.

Answer (score 4):

There's very little hard research on the healthful benefits of beer, though there is some observational research on both beer and (as Jens mentioned in [his answer](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/a/4731/37)) on the benefits of moderate levels of alcohol in general.

It's also been noted that there beer has a number of ingredients that are generally believed or known to be healthy, including vitamins, fiber, silicon, and others.

So, while I wouldn't base a diet on it, moderate consumption of beer is at least anecdotally a reasonably healthy habit in which to imbibe.

Answer (score 4):

Beer is a good way to prevent kidney stones (have to be sure that the person is not susceptible for uric acid stone, because in that case it's not recommended).
Also reduces risk of cardiovascular diseases, strengthens bones, plus good for your insomnia. One beer a day is generally good for your health.
just a few quick results :
https://www.organicfacts.net/health-benefits/beverage/health-benefits-of-beer.html
http://www.shape.com/healthy-eating/healthy-drinks/7-healthy-reasons-be-drinking-beer

Comment: on the note of uric acid- beer can also trigger gout (uric acid crystals in the blood), which if you're susceptible to makes beer an incredibly unhealthy option!

Answer (score 3):

While a doctor probably won't ever state that drinking beer is "healthy," doctors do provide advice on what "moderation" is.

Women who consume eight or more drinks per week are considered excessive drinkers. And for men, excess is defined as 15 or more drinks a week. (A drink is defined as just 5 ounces of wine, 12 ounces of beer or 1.5 ounces of spirits.)

Moderation is around 1-2 drinks per week or per 2 weeks.

All of this varies of course per individual's weight, current health, etc.